# gUnicorn/Flask/GAE - two processes started for processing the same http request

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, gunicorn

I have an app on Google AppEngine (Python39 standard env) running on gUnicorn and Flask. I'm making a request to the server from client-side app for a long-running operation and seeing that the request processed twice. The second process (worker) started after a while (a hour and a half) after the first one has been working.

I'm not sure is it related to gUnicorn specifically or to GAE.

The server controller has logging at the beginning :

```
@app.route("/api/campaign/generate", methods=["GET"])
def campaign_generate():
  logging.info('Entering campaign_generate');
  # some very long processing here
```

The controller is called by clicking a button from the UI app. I checked the network in DevTools in the browser that only one request fired. And I can see that there's only one request in server logs at the moment of executing of workers (more on this follow).

The whole app.yaml is like this:

```
runtime: python39
default_expiration: 0
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT server.server:app --timeout 0 --workers 2
```

So I have 2 workers with infinite timeouts, basic scaling with max instances = 1.
I expect while the app is processing one request for a long-running operation, another worker is available for serving.
I don't expect the second worker will used to processing the same request, it's a nonsense (if only the user won't start another operation from another browser).
Thanks to timeout=0 I expect gUnicorn will wait indefinitely till the controller finishes. And only one thing that can hinder is GAE'e timeout. But thanks to basic-scaling it's 24 hours. So I expect the app should process requests for several hours without problem.

But what I'm seeing instead is that after the processing the request for a while another execution is started. Here's simplified logs I see in Cloud Logging:

```
13:00:58 GET /api/campaign/generate
13:00:59 Entering campaign_generate
..skipped
13:39:13 Starting generating zip-archive (it's something that takes a while)
14:25:49 Entering campaign_generate
```

So, at 14:25, 1:25 after the current request came another processing of the same request started!
And now there're two request processings running in parallel.
Needless to say that this increase memory pressure and doubles execution time.

When the first "worker" finished (14:29:28 in our example) its processing, its result isn't being returned to the client. It looks like gUnicorn or GAE simply abandoned the first request. And the client has to wait till the second worker finishes processing.

Why is it happening?
And how can I fix it?

Regarding http requests records in the log.
I did see only one request in Cloud Logging (the first one) when the processing was active, and even after the controller was called for the second time ('Entering campaign_generate' in logs appeared) there was not any new GET-request in the logs. But after that everything completed (actually the second processing returned a response) a mysterious second GET-request appeared. So technically after everything is done, from the server logs' view (Cloud Logging) it looks like there were two subsequent requests from the client. But there weren't! There was only one, and I can see it in the browser's DevTools.
Those two requests have different traceId and requestId http headers.

It's very hard to understand what's going on, I tried running the app locally (on the same data) but it works as intended.

Comment: Which version of Python is this?

Comment: Python 3.9     , I'll update the question with full content of app.yaml

Comment: Adding additional debug lines that print out the request headers might give you a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you did not define the worker-class in your entrypoint command, the default worker-class is `sync` type ([see gunicorn documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-class)), which may have caused the issue you observed. If you have long-running requests you should consider using `gthreads` workers instead.

**Sync (Synchronous) Workers**: The default worker type in Gunicorn. Each worker can handle only one request at a time. If a sync worker is occupied with a long-running request, it won't be able to handle another request until it's done. If the master process detects that the worker is unresponsive (due to the long-running operation), it might think the worker is stuck and restart it, leading to the behavior you're seeing.

**Gthread (Threaded) Workers**: These workers can handle multiple requests concurrently using threads. This type is more suitable for I/O-bound applications and can be more efficient in utilizing resources for long-running requests.

To start using `gthread` workers, all you need to do is to update your `entrypoint` in `app.yaml` to the following:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT server.server:app --timeout 0 --workers 2 --worker-class gthread
```